# Is the expression "either overshoot or fall short" excellent English?

Tags: expressions

> A. Medical treatments **either overshoot or fall short**.

> B. Medical treatments **either overshoot or fall short of the mark**.

I would like to know if the figurative expression "either overshoot or fall short" is excellent English and whether the sentence can end with "fall short" or it needs to include "of the mark" or something else after "fall short".

Comment: Your final paragraph explains the problem clearly: overdosing can cause further problems and underdosing can fail to achieve the desired improvements in the patient's condition. You could use the ballistic metaphor as a flourish at the end of an essay but it would not serve as a *substitute* for your final paragraph. That said, I don't find the "overshooting" metaphor to be an apt parallel for side effects. A final note: the meaning of "medical treatments" is not limited to the administration of medicines, at least not in everyday English, where it can include other forms of intervention.

Comment: The metaphors seem to be mixed. Is the treatment the archer or the arrow?

Comment: It's still easy to imagine the meaning, but because of the mixing it's slightly less excellent stylistically. I would indeed say that "shoot" refers to the person holding the weapon (bow, gun, etc.), while "fly" and "fall" refer to the projectile (arrow, bullet, etc.).

Comment: You can certainly pair "undershoot" and "overshoot", though. Also, I find the metaphor slightly off, because the meaning is about the dosage being too high/low, but the metaphor is about going too far/not far enough (e.g. prescribing chemo for the flu or cough drops for cancer). But reflecting on this further, I don't think the whole expression is invalid. I think if you say that the treatments overshoot or undershoot the *mark* or the *target*, even though the complement is syntactically necessary, it helps unify the metaphor.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Yes, if you think about it it seems awkward, but both *overshoot* and *fall short* are so common in their idiomatic sense that most people don't think about them being sort-of incompatible with each other. (Or just think of an airplane pilot - who can both *overshoot* the plane and *fall short* of the mark themselves :))

Comment: @MaciejStachowski I quite agree and I find it pretty transparent -- but since the question asked not whether it was *average* English but *excellent* English I'm being nitpicky :) One has to have an average to excel!

Comment: overshoot or fall short of **the mark**. Both expressions require of the mark in this context.

Answer (score 0):

It's a perfectly correct sentence - [fall short](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fall-short) can be both transitive and intransitive, so you don't always need to say "fall short of the mark" and can use it on its own:

> You have had more opportunities than most, and yet you, too, fall short.

Whether it's "excellent" is subjective - I find it to be a pretty nice, concise sentence.

Answer (score -1):

There are situations where patients do not respond sufficiently to drug treatments or where side effects occur and the patient must stop the treatment. In some cases surgery is an option. If you were writing an essay or article comparing the pros and cons of medication with the pros and cons of surgery as remedies for a particular condition, you would  likely have a section devoted to the challenge of finding the proper dose for patients, since it is rarely as simple as a calculation based on their body weight; underdosing can fail to achieve the desired results and overdosing can cause unwanted side effects. The medical professional typically writes a script for some "standard" dose and then reduces or increases the dose after a period of monitoring, and often that process is repeated several times.

If you were looking for a pithy analogy or metaphor for the *process* of "zeroing in on the proper dose", the "bracketing"of ballistics does work. The ballistic missile is launched, where it lands is measured, and if the missile has overshot the target (*pace* Luke Sawczak, the missile can overshoot), trajectory adjustments are made to reduce the distance, and if that adjustment causes the missile to undershoot the target, another adjustment is made to increase the distance, lower than the previous maximum, until the missile finally hits the target.

The ballistic metaphor refers to the process of finding the right dose. It isn't an "either/or" scenario as presented in the question.  It's not like the shooter has only one shell or one arrow.

Comment: I said it works for the process of *finding the right dose*, which in the "bracketing" technique of ballistics requires several adjustments to be made to "zero in on" the target dose. Your question poses the situation as an either/or choice, as though the only two options were overshooting or undershooting, and that hitting the mark was never a possibility.

Comment: Medical professionals often must repeat the process of increasing and reducing the dose several times, in ever smaller increments, in order to "zero in" on the proper dose for the patient.

Comment: Note that the standard dictionaries don't all have this meaning for "zero in" and define it as simply "taking aim". In a ballistics context, "zeroing in" refers to an *iterative process of adjustment in ever-decreasing increments* that results in the missile hitting the target.